# "in how far" vs " how far"

Tags: word-choice

Please have a look at this assignment:

> "Point out **in how far** the American Dream has become a nightmare."

It is taken from a German textbook for English learners at an advanced level ("The New Pathway Advanced"- Schöningh p.140):

[image]"

For me personally "in how far" sounds totally normal (I'm German). However, a British person told me that it sounds wrong to his ears and that it should be "how far".
So I was wondering whether "in how far" is American and "how far" rather British?
Or let me ask, is there a rule when to use "in how far" and when "how far"?

Comment: I agree that the 'in' is unnecessary. However the sentence isn't very good anyway. I suggest changing the author.

Comment: *Describe how these aspects ....*

Comment: I am American, and agree that "in how far" is abnormal.  Presumably (as noted in an answer) the person who wrote it is German or Dutch.

Comment: "Point out **to what extent** these aspects are represented in film."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand *in how far* as synonymous to *to what extent*, as its structure is exactly the same as that of Dutch  *in hoeverre* and German *inwieweit* (both, literally, 'in how far', meaning 'to what extent'). That's what I make out of it being a native Polish speaker who is familiar with those other two languages. No idea if it's idiomatic in any native variety of English (most Google results for *in how far* I've found seem to be texts written in English by German native speakers).

Comment: That seems to be correct. Even worse, there are by now so many occurrences of that phrase that googling it makes people think it's correct. On this popular Ger-Eng site the discussion came up as early as 2005. [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/forum-questions/detail-72097-in-how-far.html) (German) Though even back then a high occurrence by Austrian and German writers was observed.

Answer (score 5):

*In how far* sounds wrong to me (UK).  The 'in' is redundant.

Comment: I agree (also UK, but I'd be surprised if it were any more acceptable to an articulate AmE speaker). I think there's erroneous conflation with, for example, *Point out (specify, identify) **in what way** these aspects are represented in the film.* But the conjunction of opposites ***out/in*** just sounds daft to me.

Comment: Sounds wrong to this Canadian too.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Grzegorz J. Rybacki. This is meant to express the interrogative form of *insofar*.

However, the term *inhowfar* does not exist, and neither does *in how far* (although maybe it should, but that's another matter). As the comments here show, it’s not clear what textbook it’s taken from nor which speaker it’s written by (whether German or Dutch).

Since *insofar* means “to such an extent”,  the right way to express this without creating a neologism would be *to what extent*.

Comment: A good answer is complete and gives evidence showing why it is correct.
Links to external resources are encouraged.
An unsupported statement is not useful and may be subject to deletion even if it is correct.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good answer, see [answer].

Comment: Just added some information about the book the phrase was taken from and also included a photo.